# Python27 + new dev_appserver.py + debugging

Tags: google-app-engine

What king of tools allows debugging with new dev_appserver.py.

I am currently using Eclipse + Aptana (PyDev 2.7.0). I am coding in Python/JavaScript/HTML/CSS/Django Templates - all features is important so I am not using the recent version of PyDev (I am think that Django templates not works).

Want to use some Eclipse base tools, debugging with breakpoints, watches - not want use tools which force to use logging since too slow.